# Авто-пополнение через WebMoney

Tags: php, webmoney, платежи

Вот такой обработчик:

```
<?php
include("../connectdb.php");
if ($_POST['LMI_PREREQUEST'] == '1') {
  // 1) Проверяем, есть ли товар с таким id в базе данных.
  // Если такой товар не обнаружен, то выводим ошибку и прерываем работу скрипта.
  $q = "SELECT `id`, `sum` FROM `pay` WHERE id='$_POST[id]'";
  $res = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query($q));
  if(!$res[0] or $res[0]=="") {
    echo "ERR: НЕТ ТАКОГО ТОВАРА";
    exit;
  }
  // 2) Проверяем, не произошла ли подмена суммы.
  // Cравниваем стоимость товара в базе данных с той суммой, что передана нам Мерчантом.
  // Если сумма не совпадает, то выводим ошибку и прерываем работу скрипта.
  if (trim($res[1])!=trim($_POST['LMI_PAYMENT_AMOUNT'])) {
    echo "ERR: НЕВЕРНАЯ СУММА ".$_POST['LMI_PAYMENT_AMOUNT'];
    exit;
  }
  // 3) Проверяем, не произошла ли подмена кошелька.
  // Cравниваем наш настоящий кошелек с тем кошельком, который передан нам Мерчантом.
  // Если кошельки не совпадают, то выводим ошибку и прерываем работу скрипта.
  if (trim($_POST['LMI_PAYEE_PURSE'])!="Z100713203405") {
    echo "ERR: НЕВЕРНЫЙ КОШЕЛЕК ПОЛУЧАТЕЛЯ ".$_POST['LMI_PAYEE_PURSE'];
    exit;
  }
  // 4) Проверяем, указал ли пользователь свой email.
  // Если параметр $email пустой, то выводим ошибку и прерываем работу скрипта.
  if (!trim($_POST['email']) or trim($_POST['email']) == "") {
    echo "ERR: НЕ УКАЗАН EMAIL";
    exit;
  }
  // Если ошибок не возникло и мы дошли до этого места, то выводим YES
  echo "YES";
}
?>
```

И выдает ошибку при попытке пополнить

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
  if (trim($res[1])!=trim($_POST['LMI_PAYMENT_AMOUNT'])) {
echo "ERR: НЕВЕРНАЯ СУММА ".$_POST['LMI_PAYMENT_AMOUNT'];
exit;}
```

Проверте что возвращает trim($res[1])
думаю проблема именно в этом, вам нужно обрабатывать суммы единым типом, например float и везде это указывать